# ArrayList<superclass> but use ArrayList<subclass>.methodofsubclass

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

Im having a class Woning (house) and a subclass KoopWoning (buyable House) and a subclass HuurWoning (rentable House). KoopWoning and Huurwoning extend Woning. HuurWoning is just a Woning, whereas KoopWoning has an extra variable energylevel. KoopWoning has also a function getEnergylevel, which returns the energylevel of the KoopWoning. I also have a class Portefeuille which has an arraylist of Woningen.

Im reading all Woningen in a Portefeuille from a textfile. In a 5th class, I want to be able to sort the ArrayList of Woningen of Portefeuille (from the textfile). I have a function woningenTot(int maxprijs) which returns an ArrayList with all the Woningen that fullfil the requirement (having a price below maxprijs). These Woningen I want to print on the screen.

The problem is as follows:
It can be possible that there is also a KoopWoning in the file. In that case I also want to be able to sort on energylevel. However, I can't sort on the energylevels. I can't call the function getEnergylevel because it's an ArrayList, and Woning doesn't contain the function getEnergylevel.

So how can I solve this? If it's too vague, I could include the code, however it's quite big :O

Any help is appreciated; i have spent a couple of hours on this program, from which at least 1.5 hours on this problem alone :(

EDIT: Here is the code for class KoopWoning

```
public class KoopWoning extends Woning implements EnergiepeilWoning {
private char energiepeil;

public KoopWoning (Adres adres, int kamers, int vraagPrijs, char energiepeil) {
    super(adres, kamers, vraagPrijs);
    this.energiepeil = energiepeil; 
}

public char getEnergiepeil () {
    return energiepeil;
}

public boolean compareEnergiepeil (Object other) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (other instanceof KoopWoning) {
        KoopWoning that = (KoopWoning) other;
        res = (this.getEnergiepeil() == that.getEnergiepeil());
    }
    return res; 
}

public String toString () {
    String res = adres + ", " + kamers + " kamers, prijs " + prijs + ", energiepeil " + energiepeil;
    return res;
}
```

And here is the code for class Woning

```
public class Woning {
protected int kamers;
protected int prijs;
protected Adres adres;
protected String tag;

public Woning (Adres adres, int kamers, int prijs) {
    this.adres = adres;
    this.kamers = kamers;
    this.prijs = prijs;     
}

public String toString () {
    String res = adres + ", " + kamers + " kamers, prijs " + prijs;
    return res;
}

public void setTag (String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getTag () {
    return tag;
}

public boolean kostHooguit (int maxprijs) {
    return (prijs <= maxprijs);
}

public boolean equals (Object other) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (other instanceof Woning) {
        Woning that = (Woning) other;
        if (this.adres.equals(that.adres))
            res = true;
    }
    return res;
}

public static Woning read (Scanner sc) {
    try {
        Adres adress = Adres.read(sc);
        int kamer = sc.nextInt();
        sc.next();
        sc.next();
        int prijs = sc.nextInt();
        String check = sc.next();
        if (check.equals("energiepeil")) {
            char peil = sc.next().charAt(0);
            KoopWoning kwoning = new KoopWoning (adress, kamer, prijs, peil);
            return kwoning;
        }
        else {
            Woning woning = new Woning (adress, kamer, prijs);
            return woning;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Woning: Exception is caught");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Adres adress = new Adres ("", "", "", "");
        Woning woning = new Woning (adress, 0, 0);
        return woning;
    }
}
}
```

And lastly, the code for the class Portefeuille

```
public class Portefeuille {

private ArrayList<Woning> woninglijst;

public Portefeuille () {
    woninglijst = new ArrayList<Woning>();
}

public void voegToe (Woning woning) {
    if (!woninglijst.contains(woning))
        woninglijst.add(woning);
}

public ArrayList<Woning> woningenTot (int maxprijs) {
    ArrayList<Woning> woninglijst2 = new ArrayList<Woning>();
    for (int i = 0; i < woninglijst.size(); i++) {
        if(woninglijst.get(i).kostHooguit(maxprijs))
            woninglijst2.add(woninglijst.get(i));
    }
    return woninglijst2;
}

public String toStringExt () {
    String res = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < woninglijst.size(); i++)
        res = res + woninglijst.get(i).toString() + "; ";
    if (woninglijst.size() != 0)
        res = res.substring (0, res.length() - 2);
    res = res + "]";
    return res;
}

public String toString () {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < woninglijst.size(); i++)
        res = woninglijst.get(i).toString2();
    return res;
}

public boolean equals (Object other) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (other instanceof Portefeuille) {
        Portefeuille that = (Portefeuille) other;
        if (this.woninglijst.size() == that.woninglijst.size()) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < this.woninglijst.size() && this.woninglijst.get(i).equals(that.woninglijst.get(i)))
                i = i + 1;
            res = (i == this.woninglijst.size());
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static Portefeuille read (String infile) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File(infile));
        ArrayList<Woning> wlijst = new ArrayList<Woning>();
        Portefeuille p = new Portefeuille();
        int woningen = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < woningen) {
            sc.nextLine();
            String tag = sc.nextLine();
            wlijst.add(Woning.read(sc));
            p.voegToe(wlijst.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        sc.close();
        return p;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Portefeuille: Exception is caught");
        Portefeuille p = new Portefeuille();
        return p;
    }   
}
}
```

### EDIT

I fixed it myself. Thanks for answering you all :)

Comment: How do you want to sort things that have no energy level? If you want to sort the whole lot then you need to decide where the items that don't have an energy level go.

Comment: You need to include the *relevant* part of the code, which sounds like it shouldn't be that big. Now that you've described the hierarchy, just the attempt at sorting and the definitions of your lists should probably be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could define, on the top-level class, a method like `getSortableValue()`, and implement it to return a default field (you didn't mention the field you need to sort on for `Woningen`). In the `KoopWoning` you override this method to return the `energyLevel` instead. Then you always sort on the value returned by `getSortableValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `Comparator` on `Woning` that determines the relative ordering of two `Woning`. You could do this either by having a method that looks at the actual types of the two arguments and then acts appropriately, or, better, by having an overrideable method of `Woning` that returns some value that you can use for sorting purposes.

If, for instance, you decide that anything with an energy level should come after anything without one, then you can have `KoopWoning` return something with the energy level in the high order bits of a `long`, so that it always comes out higher than anything without one (essentially you'd be setting a default energy level of zero).

Then, you can use

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, myComparator);
```

to sort the list based on the `Comparator` you've created.

There are some nice classes in the Guava library that help with `Comparator` building on multiple keys, but if your case is fairly simple, you probably won't need them.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Sorry, I rejected your edit because I got this mixed up with another answer I was in the middle of editing. I've manually applied your suggested edit (with "could" instead of "can").

Answer (score 0):

You can let the them implement `Comparable`, so like `Woning implements Comparable<Woning>`. This will let you implement the (required) method:

```
@override
public int compareTo(Woning other) {
    int result = Integer.compareto(maxPrijs, other.maxPrijs);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    result = Integer.compareto(someField, other.someField);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    // etc...
    return 0;
}
```

The subclass `KoopWoning extends Woning implements Comparable<KoopWoning>` can have a method like this:

```
@override
public int compareTo(KoopWoning other) {
    int result = Integer.compareto(energylevel, other.energylevel);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    return super.compareTo(other);
}
```

Then all you need to do is load all the Woning instances in a list and execute

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Having subclasses inherit `Comparable` is optional, so `HuurWoning` will just sort like `Woning`.

Comment: Note that `Integer.compareTo()` is new in Java 1.6 and is safer than just subtracting values (which may overflow). Similar ones exist for all primitive and basic value types.